# spring jpa - calling stored procedure based on profile

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring + jpa + hibernate to call a stored procedure from an oracle db.

Depending on whether my profile is set to `dev` or `prod` I need to create slightly different `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery`s. Currently I use the following entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MYTABLE")
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
    @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "MYSTOREDPROC",
        procedureName = "DBNAME.PACKAGE.MYSTOREDPROC", <-- this DBNAME is profile dependent
        parameters = {
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, name = "records", type = void.class),
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "id", type = String.class)})
})
public class MyEntity {...}
```

If I am in `dev`, then `DBNAME=DB_DEV`, and if in `prod`, then `DBNAME=DB_PRD`

How can I achieve this? Why does it not work if I just give it the `PACKAGE.MYSTOREDPROC` as procedure name?

Thanks for the help

Comment: why you want to define database selection during procedure execution time?  The recommeded way is to define profile based database connections and your procedures should run on that database accordingly?

Comment: because it tells me it cannot find the procedure if I leave out the dbname from the stored procedure query. I have to give it `dbname.package.procedurename`